# Reflection to get List<object> data

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to loop through a `DetailClass` objects inside a List using reflection just like for string fields, but I can't figure out how.

```
class DetailClass
{
    public string FieldDetail1 { get; set; }
    public string FieldDetail2 { get; set; }
    public string FieldDetail3 { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public List<DetailClass> Artikli { get; set; }
}

private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties();
}

var myData = new SomeClass();
var prop = GetProperties(myData);

foreach (var item in prop)
{
    if (item.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        var name = item.Name,  
        var value = item.GetValue(myData).ToString()));
    }

    //how to get name and value for data inside List<DetailClass>?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You were trying to enumerate properties of the parent class
2. `GetValue` needs the a reference to the class you are dealing with

**Code**

```
var myData = new SomeClass();
myData.Artikli = new List<DetailClass>() { new DetailClass() { FieldDetail1 = "asd", FieldDetail2 = "sdfd", FieldDetail3 = "sdfsg" } };

foreach (var obj in myData.Artikli)
{
   foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      if (item.PropertyType == typeof(string))
      {
         var name = item.Name;
         var val = item.GetValue(obj);
         Console.WriteLine(name + ", " + val);
      }
   }
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QUB4ln)

**Additional Resources**

---

[PropertyInfo.GetValue Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the property value of a specified object.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - obj
> - Type: System.Object
>
>   - The object whose property value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use your method recursively to get inside all layer of properties
2. You can check if 
   `item.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable))`
   and if true cast `(IEnumerable)item.GetValue(myData)` and iterate on the result
   recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Just like TheDude answered, you can use a recursive method like so;

```
private void Recursion(object obj)
{
    var props = GetProperties(obj);
    foreach (var item in props)
    {
        if (item.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var name = item.Name;
            var value = item.GetValue(obj)?.ToString();
        }
        else if (item.PropertyType == typeof(List<DetailClass>))
        {
            var test = (List<DetailClass>) item.GetValue(obj);
            foreach (var t in test)
            {
                Recursion(t);
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

And do whatever you want with the name and values in the list.